# Get text between two strings in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the content between 2 strings and do operation on them. For example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hD5D5/9/) you can see there are two `$toc` variables. I want to get the content between these two and make a table of content based on that. If you see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hD5D5/9/) link you'll see that it's taking all the h1,h2,h3,h4 tags and making table of content by replacing first `$toc` but I don't want all the H tags in that table of content. I want just the H tags between these two `$toc` strings. How can I do that?

What I tried

```
function createTOC(elements) {

    var tocString = '';

    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
      tocString += elements[i].outerHTML;
    }
    var $body = $('body');
    var html = $body.html();
    var newHtml = html.replace('$toc', tocString);
    $body.html(newHtml);
}
var $tocElements = $('h1, h2, h3, h4');
createTOC($tocElements);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to delimit your content with 2 different `p` tags with `$toc` inside... Just wrap what you need in a container, and take the children headings. Extra `div` won't break your layout, it doesn't have any default styles.

Comment: actually the requirement is to make table of content where user writes $toc. That I did. Now the requirement is to make separate table of content for separate part, so in the link you see there are 2 $toc, therefore I need to make two table of content. First $toc will make table of content of data till it finds second $toc, and then the second $toc will make table of content of the data till the end of document.

Comment: I see... I think the container approach still applies though. Or is it more of a markdown thing?

Comment: no, I'm not aware of what classes/ids user will use, I just need to find the string ($toc) and replace that with table of contents.

Answer (score 1):

1) find the elements which is holding the text **`$toc`**

```
var listOfTocs = $('p:contains("$toc")');
```

2) Now using **`nextUtil()`** get all the inbetween those **`p`** tags.

```
var foul = $(listOfTocs[0]).nextUntil(listOfTocs[1]);
```

3) Now filter those elements with `elements` (h1, h2, h3, h4)

```
var goal = foul.filter(elements);
```

4) To see its values just iterate

```
$.each(goal, function (i, v) {
    console.log($(v).text());
});
```

Finally,

```
function createTOC(elements) {
    var listOfTocs = $('p:contains("$toc")');
    var foul = $(listOfTocs[0]).nextUntil(listOfTocs[1]);
    var goal1 = foul.filter(elements);
    $.each(goal1, function (i, v) {
        console.log($(v).text());
    });

    var goal2 = $(listOfTocs[1]).nextUntil($("body").last()).filter(elements);
    $.each(goal2, function (i, v) {
        console.log($(v).text());
    });
}
```

Returns

> Werkwijze
>   Heading 2
>   Heading 3
>   Heading 4
>   Kwaliteitsregistraties
>
> ---
>
> Goal
>   Council of members
>   MGMT
>   IT
>   Scope
>   Environment
>   Quality
>   Wellness

Now you can make other things with it.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Please check my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538793/get-text-between-two-strings-in-jquery-or-javascript#comment30712260_20538793

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Try my updated answer.  Since you only 2 $toc, I have directly used array indexing.  otherwise you should use iterate each $toc and find the heading inbetween them

Comment: I can't use `'p:contains("$toc")` as I am not sure whether customer will write `$toc` in `<p>` or `<div>` or whatever. I just need to look for the text $toc.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak ohh. Ok let me try some other approach.  But to confirm remaining items are okay right?

Comment: Hi tried your solution in fiddle, it didn't work. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hD5D5/10/). Also to help you understand the complete problem, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515565/using-jquery-to-find-a-text-and-make-toc-based-on-that

Comment: @ChankeyPathak actually I thought you will make it.  Ok here is what I tried previously http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/hD5D5/13/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. Just want to see how to remove the dependency on tags from solution.

Comment: Praveen did you find any other way to solve this? (tag independent)